# Reflection: Cast Array Of Objects To List

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-3.5

Code:

```
object arrayOfObjs = new object[]{ 1, "test"};
```

Now I want to Add new element to this array. Is it possible like:

```
((IEnumerable)arrayOfObjs).Cast<object>().ToList().Add("test123");
```

This code doesn't add item.

**Edit:**

if we will make it strongly typed:

```
object arrayOfObjs = new string[]{ "1", "test"};
```

Adding work, thx:

```
var tmp = ((IEnumerable)arrayOfObjs).Cast<object>().ToList();
tmp.Add("test123");
```

How can we cast this list back to Array of T, if type is unknown at design time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to capture the result in a local variable:

```
var items = ((IEnumerable)arrayOfObjs).Cast<object>().ToList();

items.Add("test123");
```

Comment: Thx. Found solution var arr = Array.CreateInstance(tag.GetType().GetElementType(), tt.Count);
                        Array.Copy(tt.ToArray(), arr, tt.Count);